# Indices across collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

This question has been asked in a variety of forms, but I'm more concerned with schema design and implications:

I have two types of collections.  I would like each type to be indexed by tag and keyword for organization and searching purposes. My understanding is that indices cannot be created across collections, and the solution is to include both types in one collection, have an index on type for differentiation, and create the indices for tags and keywords within this single collection.  Is my understanding of this accurate?  Are there any downsides to this sort of schema?  How about scalability concerns (e.g., do issues with sharding arise)?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you give an example of the two types of documents? Do you need to search and return both types in the same query?

Comment: The two types are Projects and Nodes--projects actually contain nodes, although they are simply dbrefs.  I would like to return both types in the same query as well as separated by type as a method of sorting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your understanding is correct. However, instead of collating the Projects and Nodes in one collection, you can also just run two queries. This avoids some of the scalability "issues" perhaps as the two collections can be sharded and balanced separately.
And two indexed lookups are not going to be terrible slower than just one.